# sqlite.net PCL throws TypeInitalizationException

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

We changed from sqlite-net to sqlite.net PCL edition. Our project worked fine with the old one - with the PCL edition, we now have to explicitely declare our platform by using.

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWin32(),  Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName));
```

But now, when I call this line, we get a

> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for  "SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.SQLiteApiWin32Internal" threw an exception.

The inner Exception tells us

> {"Failed to load native sqlite library"}

Stacktrace:

> at SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.SQLiteApiWin32Internal.sqlite3_open_v2(Byte[] filename, IntPtr& db, Int32 flags, IntPtr zvfs)
>
> at SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.SQLiteApiWin32.Open(Byte[] filename, IDbHandle& db, Int32 flags, IntPtr zvfs)
>
> at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks, IBlobSerializer serializer, IDictionary`2 tableMappings, IDictionary`2 extraTypeMappings, IContractResolver resolver)
>
> at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks, IBlobSerializer serializer, IDictionary`2 tableMappings, IDictionary`2 extraTypeMappings, IContractResolver resolver)

However the sqlite3.dll is in the application folder and it actually did work with the unforked version. I played around with compiling for x86 and x64 and downloaded the latest sqlite3.dll for Win32 but all without success. What are we missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem in a tests project.
Solved it by adding the package http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core for the SQLitePlatformWin32.

Although not listed as a dependency in the actual version, it was in previous one of the platform's nuget package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32/)

Additionally: in case of using SQLitePlatformGeneric a copy of sqlite3.dll should be placed in the output directory.

Comment: This was the solution - it was the interop dll files that were missing and after adding the core package to my project it also added those files. Interestingly I didn't have to add the files as a direct dependency in my class lib project (where I had the sqlite pcl files) but to my gui project which is dependend on the class lib to get it to work.

Comment: Make sure you pick the correct .Core package (x86/x64), not the MSIL .Core package.

Comment: what is the difference between SQLitePlatformWin32 and SQLitePlatformGeneric?

Comment: @batmaci
From the readme on the platform's git repo https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL#sqliteconnection
"Win32 (bundles sqlite binaries for windows, works on both x86 and x64 automatically)"
"Generic (net4 project without any sqlite3 binaries, requires sqlite installed in the OS)"